# Getting simple ECM Model from VECM in tsa python

Tags: python, cointegration

Can I get a simple Error Correction Model of the form $$
Y_{t}-Y_{t-1}=\theta _{1}\Delta X_{t}+\theta
_{2}(Y_{t-1}-\alpha X_{t-1} - \beta)+\epsilon _{t}
$$ using the *statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECM* package in Python.

I mean how will I have to set my variables for achieving so?

Thanks